# Latest Certification for each unqiue individual employee

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I joined a few tables in order to get data pertaining to certification by employees. I have a query that gives me the employee id, name, certification start date JPM_DATE_6, certification end date JPM_DATE_3 and the list of all the certifications (JPM_DESCR90) concatenated and separated by ',' in a column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.EMPLID, A.JOBCODE, A.JOBCODE_DESCR, A.EMPL_STATUS, 
A.LOCATION, A.LOCATION_DESCR, A.NAME, E.EMAILID, B.EMPLID, E.OPRID,LISTAGG(C.JPM_DESCR90,',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY 
C.JPM_DESCR90) AS CertConcat
FROM PS_NPS_VIEW_ALL A, (PS_PERSON_NAME B LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_NPS_LIC_VW_RPT 
C ON  B.EMPLID = C.EMPLID ), PSOPRDEFN E
WHERE ( A.EFFDT =
    (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_NPS_VIEW_ALL A_ED
    WHERE A.EMPLID = A_ED.EMPLID
      AND A.EMPL_RCD = A_ED.EMPL_RCD
      AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE)
AND A.EFFSEQ =
    (SELECT MAX(A_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_NPS_VIEW_ALL A_ES
    WHERE A.EMPLID = A_ES.EMPLID
      AND A.EMPL_RCD = A_ES.EMPL_RCD
      AND A.EFFDT = A_ES.EFFDT)
 AND A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID
 AND A.EMPLID = E.EMPLID
 AND A.PER_ORG = 'EMP'
 AND A.EMPL_STATUS='A'
 AND A.PAYGROUP NOT IN ('SUM','CWR'))
GROUP BY A.EMPLID, A.JOBCODE,A.JOBCODE_DESCR, A.EMPL_STATUS, A.LOCATION, 
A.LOCATION_DESCR, A.NAME, E.EMAILID, B.EMPLID, E.OPRID;
```

This gave me 8257 rows. I then tried to get data for each unique employee id whereby I would get only one certification i.e.  highest/latest certification which had the highest certification end date JPM_DATE_3 and certification name (JPM_DESCR90)

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.EMPLID,A.JOBCODE, A.JOBCODE_DESCR, A.EMPL_STATUS, 
A.LOCATION, A.LOCATION_DESCR, A.NAME, E.EMAILID, B.EMPLID, E.OPRID, 
JPM_DATE_3 ,JPM_DATE_6,JPM_DESCR90
FROM PS_NPS_VIEW_ALL A, (PS_PERSON_NAME B LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_NPS_LIC_VW_RPT 
C ON  B.EMPLID = C.EMPLID ), PSOPRDEFN E
WHERE ( A.EFFDT =
    (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_NPS_VIEW_ALL A_ED
    WHERE A.EMPLID = A_ED.EMPLID
      AND A.EMPL_RCD = A_ED.EMPL_RCD
      AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE)
AND A.EFFSEQ =
    (SELECT MAX(A_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_NPS_VIEW_ALL A_ES
    WHERE A.EMPLID = A_ES.EMPLID
      AND A.EMPL_RCD = A_ES.EMPL_RCD
      AND A.EFFDT = A_ES.EFFDT)
 AND A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID
 AND A.EMPLID = E.EMPLID
 AND A.PER_ORG = 'EMP'
 AND A.EMPL_STATUS='A'
 AND A.PAYGROUP NOT IN ('SUM','CWR'))
 AND C.JPM_DATE_3=(SELECT MAX(JPM_DATE_3) FROM PS_NPS_LIC_VW_RPT V WHERE 
V.EMPLID=A.EMPLID and V.EMPLID=B.EMPLID AND V.EMPLID=C.EMPLID AND 
V.EMPLID=E.EMPLID )
 GROUP BY A.EMPLID,A.JOBCODE, A.JOBCODE_DESCR, A.EMPL_STATUS, A.LOCATION, 
A.LOCATION_DESCR, A.NAME, E.EMAILID, B.EMPLID, E.OPRID, JPM_DATE_3 
,JPM_DATE_6,JPM_DESCR90;
```

However, this gave me 5807 unique rows . On further research I found that there were quite a few JPM_DATE_3 values and JPM_DATE_6 values that were null and I was therefore not getting the count that I wanted. Please suggest an alteration to the query that will give me unique employee ids. the latest certifications JPM_DESCR90 for the highest date JPM_DATE_3, and would also give me the rows where JPM_DATE_3 is null so that I can have 8257 unique rows as I should have for each employee id.

Answer (score 0):

It is top-n query, you are looking for last rows here and there. Easiest way is to use `row_number()`, you have to be only careful with `partition by` and `order by` clauses. Then take first row for each employee, certificate.

Here is query joining two tasks, it lists all certificates and also shows details of the latest:

```
select emplid, name, oprid, jpm_date_3 as last_cert_date3, jpm_date_6 as last_cert_date6,
       jpm_descr90 as last_cert_descr, all_certificates
  from (
    select a.emplid, a.name, e.oprid, c.jpm_date_3, c.jpm_date_6, c.jpm_descr90,
           listagg(c.jpm_descr90,',') within group (order by c.jpm_descr90) 
             over (partition by a.emplid) as all_certificates,
           row_number() over (partition by a.emplid order by jpm_date_3 desc) rnc
      from (
        select ps_nps_view_all.*, 
               row_number() over (partition by emplid, empl_rcd 
                                  order by effdt desc, effseq desc) rna
          from ps_nps_view_all
          where per_org = 'EMP' and empl_status = 'A' 
            and paygroup not in ('SUM', 'CWR') and effdt <= sysdate ) a
      join ps_person_name         b on b.emplid = a.emplid
      left join ps_nps_lic_vw_rpt c on c.emplid = a.emplid
      join psoprdefn              e on e.emplid = a.emplid
      where rna = 1 )
  where rnc = 1
```

<sup>**[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a29c247f97b1a9a6f914ae49ff0c0bd0)**  (John has no certificates, Tom has two and also two rows in main table, we take last one.)</sup>

Please note that analytical functions (`row_number`, `listagg` with `over` clause) allows you to touch data only once, no need to make self-joins and seek max values in subqueries. Also please use joins in ansi standard, it makes things more readable.

The issue in your query is that you left joined certificates, but then in `where` clause you tried to find last one (`... AND C.JPM_DATE_3= ...`) which changed left join to inner join and part of rows was lost.

Comment: I'm getting over 18000 rows here, I was expecting not more than 8300 or 8400

Comment: Only you are able to find and decide what to do in some situations, I do not know what is the meaning of columns like `empl_rcd`. You see your data and output for particular employee and know if there are rows which should be filtered for some reason. I explained the logic and showed you working demo. If you are able to show us sample data based on my fiddle and explain more we can help more.